# LoadLibrary(...) failing with error code 1627:ERROR_FUNCTION_FAILED

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I am trying to call the LoadLibrary for a dll which is placed in the exe path. 
it is giving error as ERROR_FUNCTION_FAILED. Below is the code, Please let me know the cause for 1627

```
    typedef int (__stdcall  *func)();
    int DynamicLoad_Lib()
    {
        func  call;
        int  iReturn;
        cout<<"\n\n DynamicLoad_Lib \n\n";
        HINSTANCE hinstLib = LoadLibrary(L"MYLib.dll");
        cout<<"\n\nGetLastError() "<<GetLastError()<<"\n";             
        if(hinstLib == NULL)
            return 0;
        call = (func_another)GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "Initialize");
        if(call == NULL)
        {
            FreeLibrary(hinstLib);
            return 0;
        }
        iReturn = (*call)();
        call = (func)GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "Terminate");
        if(call == NULL)
        {
            FreeLibrary(hinstLib);
            return 0;
        }
        FreeLibrary(hinstLib);
        return 1;
    }

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    DynamicLoad_Lib();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `func_another` is not defined anywhere, and why is it not `func`?  Post real code.

Comment: You are calling GetLastError(), but you do not know if LoadLibrary actually failed at that point. Please move your GetLastError call inside the body of  `if(hinstLib == NULL)`

Comment: Thanks for the reply it is copy paste mistake. error is coming before to that cout<<"\n\nGetLastError() "<<GetLastError()<<"\n";

Comment: Are you compiling with Unicode or MultiByte charset?

Comment: Hi Johnny, i am using unicode

Answer (score 0):

This prints the last error that happened in any Windows API function:

```
    cout<<"\n\nGetLastError() "<<GetLastError()<<"\n";             
    if(hinstLib == NULL)
        return 0;
```

It should be, print any error that happened in the LoadLibrary function:

```
    if(hinstLib == NULL)
    {
        cout<<"\n\nGetLastError() "<<GetLastError()<<"\n";             
        return 0;
    }
```

[LoadLibrary RTFM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Return value
>
> If the function succeeds, the return value is a handle to the module.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is NULL. To get extended error
>   information, call GetLastError.

Comment: @user2890924  if(hinstLib == NULL) is not true your program still prints an error message.

Comment: @user2890924 That's right. So, did LoadLibrary actually succeed then ? Note that you cannot just  GetLastError wherever you want and expect it to tell you something sensible.

Comment: You are calling `GetLastError` at a time, where isn't documented to produce a meaningful value. `GetLastError` must be called **immediately**, once a condition was entered, where it returns a meaningful result, with no code in between.