# WinAPI function LoadLibrary() causing function failed during execution error

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, dll

The following code loads a dll in runtime using LoadLibrary().

```
boolean Load_Internals_dll()
{
    boolean result = true;

    //LOG_INIT;
    HINSTANCE hApexRLIO = LoadLibrary(L"APEX_RLIO_Internals.dll");

    printf("Checking getlasterror after loadlibrary:\n",GetLastError());
    if(NULL == hApexRLIO)
    {
        result = false;
        printf("[ERR]:  Unable to load dll\n");
        LOG_PRINT(" [ERR]:  Unable to load dll.\n" );

    }
    result = InitRSIDComm_Lib_Func();
    //LOG_EXIT;
    return result;
}
```

After loading the dll, the handle hApexRLIO is found to be not null, but the function GetLastError() returns system error code 1627 (Function failed during execution).

What could be the possible causes for this error?

There is not much documentation for this error code in the web,
VC++ ten gallon heads please help me solving this.

Comment: Function succeeds since the returned handle value is not null so the value returned by `GetLastEror` does not seem to be relevant at all.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41122518/loadlibrary-failing-with-error-code-1627error-function-failed

Comment: Don't call `GetLastError` unless you have an error.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: That's only approximately correct. Some API's do not set the last error code on failure, some set it on failure, while other API's do set it on success an failure. The exact rule is: Don't call `GetLastError`, unless the documentation tells you to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175.aspx) says:

> If the function succeeds, the return value is a handle to the module.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is `NULL`. To get extended error information, call `GetLastError`.

When the function succeeds, the return value is not `NULL`. This is your scenario. The documentation makes no promise as to what `GetLastError` will return in case the function succeeds. Some Win32 API functions will call `SetLastError(ERROR_SUCCESS)` before returning, but not all. This is one that does not.

In other words, there is no error. The function return value indicates success, and you should not call `GetLastError` because the value it returns is meaningless.

Comment: You aren't even guaranteed that last error will remain untouched in the case of success if you explicitlely call SetLastError(ERROR_SUCCESS) yourself before you make a call.